# useCallback within a functional component

Tags: reactjs

I defined a useCallback function in a functional component and it is used in useEffect in the same functional component. in this case, Is the function optimized?

```js
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchMetadata } from '../features/metadata/metadataSlice';
import { getChangedItems } from '../app/evergreenAPI';

const useWatchChanges = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { isLogged } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const handleChangedItems = useCallback((changedItems) => {
    console.log('...doing something with', changedItems);
  }, []);

  const fetchChangedItems = async () => {
    if (!isLogged) return false;
    try {
      const changedItems = await getChangedItems();
      changedItems &&
        setTimeout(() => {
          handleChangedItems(changedItems);
        });
      fetchChangedItems();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      fetchChangedItems();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchChangedItems();
  }, [isLogged, fetchChangedItems]);
};

export default useWatchChanges;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing dependencies in your useCallback dependency array.

```
 const handleChangedItems = useCallback((changedItems) => {
    console.log('...doing something with', changedItems);
  }, [changedItems]);
```

Moreover it does not make any sense to use useCallback here probably, as useCallback also takes execution time and resources. But your handleChangedItems does not do anything that is worth to put into useCallback because of execution time / resources. Please have a look at:

https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback

Comment: `changedItems` is passed as an argument so it can't be added to the dependency array.